# What's the right approach to aggregate information from distinct components in layered software?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

There's much information on the internet about layered software design, but I could not find the answer for a common problem: should I aggregate information from distinct components (or entities) acessing sibling components or components from the layer below?

Suppose I have the following scenario:

Business Layer: `ConsumerBO`, `OrdersBO`, `MessagesBO` ...
Data Layer: `ConsumerDAO`, `OrdersDAO`, `MessagesDAO` ...

The relation between `ConsumerBO` x `ConsumerDAO`, `OrdersBO` x `OrdersDAO` and so on is clear. But if I ever need to write a method on `ConsumersBO` that aggregates information from `ConsumersDAO`, `OrdersDAO` and `MessagesDAO`, should I do it by making `ConsumersBO` access methods from its siblings (eg.: `OrderBO` and `MessagesBO`) OR from components on the layer below (eg.: `OrdersDAO`, `MessagesDAO`)? Why?

**[edit]** rewriting this question due to down votes ..

Comment: As a side note I usually using the sibling components approach, for reasons like avoiding replicating logic that is already implemented on the sibling component (and that will be lost if we go directly on the layer below). But on the n-tier pattern articles I don't find any "formal" indication that it's the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, try to make your business classes depend on their siblings. This aims to reduce the coupling between the layers which is always a good thing.

Notice that Business Layer should never depend directly on Data Layer because the former is more abstract than the later. Often we let business classes depend on interfaces which are implemented by classes in Data Layer. For example, the `CustomerBO` will use the `ICustomerDAO` interface which belongs to Business Layer, instead of the concrete `CustomerDAO` class which belongs to Data Layer.